# How to convert date TextView to Long to compare with current date

Tags: java, android, date

I have a problem, with date comparison. I have a date coming from a TextView (normally stored in SQLite Text field). The TextView rowduedate carries a date with the value: "2012/10/01 15:16"
If I out-comment the code I pasted below, it works fine and R.id.rowduedate is displayed. So it isn't empty. However I get the following error in the LogCat:

```
11-01 15:16:55.445: E/AndroidRuntime(783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 15:16:55.445: E/AndroidRuntime(783): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid   long: ""
11-01 15:16:55.445: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at   java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
11-01 15:16:55.445: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:346)
11-01 15:16:55.445: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
11-01 15:16:55.445: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.demo.notepad3.Notepadv3$1.setViewValue(Notepadv3.java:100)
```

This is the code:

```
TextView dueDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowduedate);
String due = (String) dueDate.getText().toString();

if(due!=null){
Long longDue = Long.parseLong(due);
String now = new Date().toString();
Long longNow = Long.parseLong(now);

if(longDue <= longNow){

       dueDate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}               
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell your code how the date is formatted so it can extract the time from it.

```
String strDate = "2007-12-25";
SimpleDateFormat Formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date myDate    = Formatter.parse(strDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to parse an empty string, be careful about that.

Assuming that your dueDate:TextView contains a valid date in the following format "2012/10/01 15:16":

```
long due = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm").parse(dueDate.getText().toString()).getTime();

if (due <= System.currentTimeMillis()) 
    dueDate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

That should help,

Answer (score 0):

do not compare the dates by By parsing the date string into `Long`

Here is the way you can compare date values. check it

```
TextView dueDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowduedate);
String due = (String) dueDate.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat parser=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
Date d = null;
Date now = new Date();
if(due!=null){
try {
  d = parser.parse(due);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(d.before(now){

       dueDate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}               
}
```